# Changing Django's tag colors in PyCharm

Tags: pycharm

I wanted to change `{{` to a different color, but the default Colors and Fonts interface does not allow me to do that. I can change `{%` but not `{{`, so how do I add a custom rule?

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in the current version (2.7.2). Feature request is submitted, [please vote](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-9895).